# how to store auto generated files in a different AWS S3 folder while running Tableau using Athena connector?

Tags: amazon-s3, tableau-api, amazon-athena

I am using Athena to connect a single csv file stored in AWS S3 folder with Tableau Desktop and have been successful in connecting the S3 data using Athena.
However, when I perform any activity in Tableau like drag and drop, slice and dice, for each activity, an auto generated csv and a metadata gets saved in the same folder as my input file.
Due to this additional files getting auto-generated in the same input file folder, the visuals in Tableau also get affected (due to additional records).

How do i ensure that, for any activity i perform in Tableau, the auto-generated files get stored in a different folder (rather than the same folder from where the input file is being called) ?
This will solve my problem as the visuals and the analysis will show correct numbers.

Currently, the work-around that I am using is after every activity I perform in Tableau (slice,filter, etc..), i go back to the S3 folder, delete the additional files that got auto-generated, then continue with activity in Tableau, then back to S3 folder for deletion, etc... (Definitely not the ideal way).

While executing Athena query, I am storing the query results in a different folder, because there is a provision for doing the same.

Please suggest if there is a similar provision for storing the auto-generated files (while working on Tableau) in a different folder ?

P.S. If there is an option of preventing these files from getting generated, that will also be helpful.

- Anand

Comment: Are these files being generated by Athena? If so, you can go to the **Settings** in the Amazon Athena console and provide a different **Query result location**. This can be done via CLI/API too if desired. This setting is stored in an [Athena workgroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/manage-queries-control-costs-with-workgroups.html).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that the auto-generated files get stored in a different folder?

In order to store results of you queries in a different location, you need to specify different path for **S3 Staging Directory**. In order to do that, you need to **Edit Connection** to AWS Athena.

[image: edit connection]
[image: staging directory]

Here we did everything within Tableau itself, but the same result can be accomplished within AWS Athena settings for query result locaion

> If there is an option of preventing these files from getting generated, that will also be helpful.

On the left side of the toolbar, there is an option **Pause/Resume Auto Updates**. When paused, Tableau doesn't send new query to AWS Athena.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ilya Kisil. Making necessary adjustments in the staging directory solved my problem.

Comment: @Anand Subramanian feel free to accept this answer, so that your question won't appear in unanswered section)